# How can I get line coordinates that readed by tesseract?

Tags: computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

Is there any way to read the image line by line with tesseract and get the coordinates of lines? Normally I can read each word tesseract returns dictionary and I can get all positions but no option for the line coordinates? I'm using psm 6 to read line by line but even I use it I receive word's coordinates

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang="eng", output_type=Output.DICT)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can group together the words belonging to each line and find the lines bounding box from left-most and right-most words bounding box.
Below is the python implementation to group the words together for each line.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang="eng", output_type=Output.DICT)

data = {}
for i in range(len(text['line_num'])):
    txt = text['text'][i]
    block_num = text['block_num'][i]
    line_num = text['line_num'][i]
    top, left = text['top'][i], text['left'][i]
    width, height = text['width'][i], text['height'][i]
    if not (txt == '' or txt.isspace()):
        tup = (txt, left, top, width, height)
        if block_num in data:
            if line_num in data[block_num]:
                data[block_num][line_num].append(tup)
            else:
                data[block_num][line_num] = [tup]
        else:
            data[block_num] = {}
            data[block_num][line_num] = [tup]

linedata = {}
idx = 0
for _, b  in data.items():
    for _, l in b.items():
        linedata[idx] = l
        idx += 1
line_idx = 1
for _, line in linedata.items():
     xmin, ymin = line[0][1], line[0][2]
     xmax, ymax = (line[-1][1] + line[-1][3]), (line[-1][2] + line[-1][4])
     print("Line {} : {}, {}, {}, {}".format(line_idx, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
     line_idx += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer flamelite, we have lines and coordinates. Now I need to reach specific index value is the given in dictionary by tesseract which line has that specific index

Comment: These lines are sorted in top to bottom order so accordingly you can find the lines at specific index

Comment: Actually what I meant is when I get result from tesseract as dictionary each word has an index ;
`['', '', '', '', '“İGDAŞ', '', '', '', 'İİ', 'Y', '', 'Sanayi', 've', 'Ticaret', 'A.Ş.', ';', 'O', 'A', '', 'Kazım', 'Karabekir', 'Cd.No:4', 'J', ')', '', '', '', 'B.Mükellefler', 'V.D.4700022607', 'Belge', 'No:', '', '', '', ']` in that dic for example 4 index like  "İGDAŞ" and I want to find that index in the lines that your code created. it can be in any line.